# How to let users know they have CC subtitles available in a YouTube video?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I have my YouTube channel mostly in Czech and I add English subtitles for my videos. But since the subtitles are not ON by default, I am concerned that many users won't notice that the English subtitles are available. Half a year ago it was possible to add annotations to the video, so I did it [this way](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BOegjSIrFN0):

[image]

But this is no longer possible since YouTube no longer allows to add these annotations to new videos.

**So, are there ways how to notify users that the subtitles are available (besides putting the message directly into the video, I cannot do it for older videos..), or have subtitles somehow turned on for them by default (for users with English language)?**

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is use translated meta data: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6289575

So, if your video title is "kočka", you can use the translated title for English to say "cat [english subtitles]", or use the description to say "Note: English subtitles available".

Answer (score 0):

You could add the cc message using a video editing program just like you would if you were adding lower thirds or titles, then upload to YouTube. If you are uploading  directly from your phone, there are plenty of free apps that will do this, too.

Comment: ok, that's the obvious solution, this is what I refered to in the question by  "besides putting the message directly into the video, I cannot do it for older videos" (without losing the views)